# s3 event notification configuration error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to setup S3 event notification which will trigger a lambda function on uploading an object to that bucket. But when I select the combination attached in the image below:

[image]

I keep getting the following error:

```
Configurations overlap. Configurations on the same bucket cannot share a common event type.
```

Basically I want to track all the object events related to modification and creation. Hence I selected the other 3 events. Could anyone please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have opted `All object create events`, doesn't require to select PUT, POST, or COPY.

**All object create events** = s3:ObjectCreated:*

```
s3:ObjectCreated:Put – An object was created by an HTTP PUT operation.
s3:ObjectCreated:Post – An object was created by HTTP POST operation.
s3:ObjectCreated:Copy – An object was created an S3 copy operation.
s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload – An object was created by the completion of a S3 multi-part upload.
s3:ObjectCreated:* – An object was created by one of the event types listed above or by a similar object creation event added in the future.
```